# Como inserir dados em uma tabela especializada?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, postgresql, tabela-banco-de-dados, sql-insert

Tenho duas tabelas, conforme o seguinte projeto lógico:

Pessoa(**CPF**, RG, Nome, Endereco, Cidade, Estado, DataNascimento)

Cliente(**CPF**, Telefone)
CPF referencia Pessoa

Existem outras especializações da entidade pessoa, porém não convém listar todas elas.

Gostaria de saber como faço uma inserção nessa estrutura. Serão dois inserts ou existem algo mais "correto"?

Comment: Talvez o mais correto é não fazer isso. Não sei porque o pessoal anda fazendo modelagens assim. Duvido que a pessoa consegue dar uma boa explicação para fazer isso.

Comment: Você fala que generalização/especialização é algo ruim?

Comment: Normalmente generalização é para coisa abstrata, não concreta.

Comment: O que você deseja é que uma pessoa possa ter diversos telefones? Talvez esteja utilizando erroneamente o termo "especialização". Insira um registro em "Pessoa" e a seguir todos os registros em "Cliente".

Comment: Usei telefone como exemplo, o que preciso saber é como fazer a inserção. Obrigado.

Comment: Insira a pessoa. Depois insira os telefones, com um INSERT para cada telefone da pessoa.

Answer (score -2):

Tem que ser dois inserts mas obrigatoriamente em uma mesma transação, se falhar o segundo insert chama-se o rollback.